# iOS: Make content (text) in table view cell editable, but only in edit mode

Tags: ios, tableview, cell, edit

I know this has been asked a lot of times but theres so much different information and different cases, I just don't understand where to begin and cannot get it working in my app.

In my app I have a table view and I'm using a NSFetchedResultsController. In normal mode, the table cells shouldn't be editable but instead each click should be a segue to a new viewcontroller (which works). In edit mode however I want that if you click on the cell, that you edit the text and this gets automatically stored to the database. And here I don't have a clue.

I want it as simple as possible. What I've read so far I guess I have to subclass UITableViewCell and a TextField. Here's already my first question: In each post about this, the TextField is init with a Rect, however how do I know the exact width and height of my cells?

And do I add this cell directly in the cellForRowAtIndexPath? Or only if the mode gets changed to edit? And some posts suggest you have to be the delegate for UITextField, but why?

And is there some sample code for about exact the problem I have? I wasn't able to find it...